# Not able to call function with concrete class pointer, if it is derived from abstract class

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, abstract-class

I am using "g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3" to run my code. Both are programs are compiled.

(1.) 
There is Segmentation fault at runtime in below program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Abstract { 
  public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

class A : public Abstract {
  public:
    void func() { cout << "func()" << endl; }
};

int main() {
  A *ao;
  ao->func(); //--> Segmentation fault`<br/>
/*
if we do
A *ao = new A;
ao->func();
then its working
*/
  return 0;
}
```

Why this behavior is observed, when A is now concrete class as it defined Abstracts method?

(2)
Here it is working, if class is not derived from abstract class.

```
class A {
  public:
    void func() { cout << "func()" << endl; }
};

int main() {
  A *ao;
  ao->func();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: All of your examples have undefined behavior.

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow are written using Markdown. Please learn to use MarkDown and format the code examples properly - it is not difficult.

Answer (score 0):

When you use,

```
A *ao;
ao->func(); //--> Segmentation fault
```

`ao` is not initialized to point to a valid object. Calling a member function on such a pointer leads to undefined behavior. In your case, that manifests as segmentation fault.

The fact that it works when there is no abstract base class is an unintended consequence of undefined behavior, in this case seemingly sane behavior.

On a practical note, the seemingly sane behavior is a result of the fact that you are not using any member variables of `A` in the call. In the case of an abstract base class, the virtual table is used. Since the pointer is not initialized to point to a valid object, the attempt to access the virtual table results in segmentation fault.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ: in terms of displaying the hoped-for text and *ostensibly* not doing anything unexpected, it may indeed be "working" - which is different from being coded in such a way that there's a guarantee that it's "not doing anything unexpected", or even that it will do the same thing the next time it's run.  Pretending not to understand the way in which elinus intends "working" doesn't help get to the bottom of the matter....

Answer (score 0):

You have undefined behaviour because you're using an uninitialised pointer as if it had been assigned the address of a valid object.  The compiler doesn't check that for you - it's up to you to point it somewhere reasonable.

What you've done is a bit like dropping a letter in a post box without writing an address on it - who knows what will happen?

You may get a segmentation fault from the first, but not the second, but that's not guaranteed by the C++ Standard to happen every time you run the program, let alone if you recompile it, change compiler arguments, modify the code, try another compiler etc..

In practice, the reason you're happening to "get away" with it when the function is not virtual is probably that the called function `func` makes no attempt to access any object data via the bogus `this` pointer passed to it (which will take on the value from `ao`): so it doesn't matter that the pointer's garbage.  When the function is `virtual` it tries to use the `this` pointer to find a pointer to the virtual dispatch table, but then the garbage pointer actually bites and your program crashes.  As above, neither behaviour is guaranteed - it's *undefined*.

Answer (score 0):

```
A *ao;
ao->func(); //--> Segmentation fault
```

ao will be having some garbage value, when you try ao->func(), you are trying to access the memory pointed to by ao and since most probably you don't have permission to access that memory segmentation fault occurs.

```
A *ao = new A;
ao->func();
then its working
```

The new operator will allocate memory for an instance of A and returns the valid pointer to ao and hence it will work fine.